# Using Not Or/Not And on Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

So I'm wondering if there is a computed string property that negates the current boolean value of a property. For example, in the computed property 'isDisabledSubmit' below, I added an exclamation mark in front of isValidEmail and isValidMessage in attempt to negate the property value. This doesn't work, but you can probably assume what I'm trying to accomplish. I could get it to work by adding two extra properties isInvalidEmail and isInvalidMessage, but this seems a bit excessive in a large app... Is there a way to do a not and and a not or/ negate a property inside an and/or?

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
contactForm: false,
contactEmail: '',
contactMessage: '',
isValidEmail: Ember.computed.match( 'contactEmail', /^.+@.+\..+$/ ),
isValidMessage: Ember.computed.gte('contactMessage.length', 10),
isDisabledSubmit: Ember.computed.or( '!isValidEmail', '!isValidMessage') 
});
```

Possible, but tedious solution

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
contactForm: false,
contactEmail: '',
contactMessage: '',
isValidEmail: Ember.computed.match( 'contactEmail', /^.+@.+\..+$/ ),
isValidMessage: Ember.computed.gte('contactMessage.length', 10),
//Add negated version of previous properties...tedious approach...
isInvalidEmail: Ember.computed.not('isValidEmail'),
isInvalidMessage: Ember.computed.not('isValidMessage'),
//
isDisabledSubmit: Ember.computed.or( 'isInvalidEmail', 'isInvalidMessage') 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short **no**.
Ember.js forces you to be explicit on what property is available and helps your code to be readable with convenient functions like `Ember.computed.match` and `Ember.computed.not`.

However, if your intention is to use these computed properties in templates, you can bypass this limitation with a custom helper. Just create a file `app/helpers/reverse.js` with the following content:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function reverse([value]) {
  return !value;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(reverse);
```

You will then be able to branch depending on the inverse of a computed property:

```
{{#if (reverse isValidEmail)}}
{{/if}}
```

Is the same as

```
{{#if isInvalidEmail}}
{{/if}}
```

Be aware this method is less explicit and only works inside templates.